# Why is EnableMenuItem not working as I expect it to?

Tags: c, winapi, menu

I am trying to create a window with a simple `File -> Open, Close, Exit` menu. However, `Close` will be disabled until the user opens a file with the `Open` menu action. The menu exists as a resource named `IDR_MENU1`.

This is my `wWinMain` function:

```
INT APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ INT nShowCmd)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG Msg;
    NONCLIENTMETRICSW ncm;
    HFONT hfDefault;
    HMENU hMenu;
    
    ZeroMemory(&ncm, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICSW));
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICSW);
    SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICSW), &ncm, FALSE);
    hfDefault = CreateFontIndirectW(&ncm.lfMessageFont);

    if (RegisterWCEX(hInstance) == (ATOM)0)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Window registration failed", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return -1;
    }

    hWnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, g_wszClassName, L"PTW", WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 600, 450, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (NULL == hWnd) 
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Window creation failed", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    EnumChildWindows(hWnd, EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)&hfDefault);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    hMenu = LoadMenuW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDR_MENU1));
    hMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0);
    if (NULL == hMenu)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (-1 == EnableMenuItem(hMenu, 1, MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED | MF_BYPOSITION))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    DrawMenuBar(hWnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&Msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my `WM_CREATE` message handler:

```
BOOL WINAPI OnCreate(HWND hWnd, LPCREATESTRUCTW lpCreateStruct)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = lpCreateStruct->hInstance;
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccx;

    iccx.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES | ICC_DATE_CLASSES;
    iccx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    if (!InitCommonControlsEx(&iccx))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

When I run this, the `Close` option is still enabled:

[image: Screenshot illustrating the menu not disabling 'Close' as expected]

Am I getting something wrong here with how I'm calling `LoadMenu` and/or `GetSubMenu`, or is it how I'm calling `EnableMenuItem`?

Comment: IDK if relevant but from [`EnableMenuItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablemenuitem) the `MF_GRAYED` includes `MF_DISABLED` action in its description, and it says "The return value specifies the previous state of the menu item (it is either `MF_DISABLED`, `MF_ENABLED`, or `MF_GRAYED`)." This implies that only one of those three values should be set (maybe ORred with other flags), but you have used two, `MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading a 2nd instance of the menu resource, separate from whatever menu is already assigned to your window.  You are disabling the menu item on this 2nd menu, and at no point is the code shown assigning the modified menu to your window.

Get rid of the call to `LoadMenuW()`, use [`GetMenu()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160) instead to obtain the `HMENU` that is actually assigned to the window.

```cpp
//hMenu = LoadMenuW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDR_MENU1));
hMenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
```